# Create table on data load in BiqQuery from Java

Tags: java, google-bigquery

According to the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating_a_table_when_you_load_data it should be possible for BigQuery to create the table from the data.

> When you load data into BigQuery, you can load data into a new table or partition, you can append data to an existing table or partition, or you can overwrite a table or partition. You do not need to create an empty table before loading data into it. You can create the new table and load your data at the same time.

However, I am getting an error that my table doesn't exist whenever I try to stream data to BigQuery from Java.

This is an example of an insert statement that works but only after I manually create my table:

```java
InsertAllResponse response = bigQuery
        .insertAll(
                InsertAllRequest
                        .newBuilder(tableId)
                        .addRow(rowContent)
                        .build()
        );
```

I can create the schema in Java and then create the table but then I have to constantly check if the schema is created before I can stream to it. `generateBigQuerySchema` is a method I created that defines the schema. The code below will fail if the schema already exists so I would have to check if it exists before I create it.

```java
InsertAllResponse response = bigQuery
        .create(requestLog.generateBigQuerySchema(tableId))
        .getBigQuery()
        .insertAll(
                InsertAllRequest
                        .newBuilder(tableId)
                        .addRow(rowContent)
                        .build()
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mixed two different *resource types* according to [API Reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/).
I mean [Jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#resource) and [Tabledata](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata#resource).

Jobs [does loading](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load) where insertAll method from Tabledata, [doesn't](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll):

> Streams data into BigQuery one record at a time without needing to run
>   a load job

I see that Google docs could be misinterpret as above because [Introduction to Loading Data into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data) references streaming inserts (insertAll). It looks like below:

> You can load data:
>
> ... By inserting individual records using [streaming inserts](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) ...

Where streaming inserts redirect to [Streaming Data into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) which tells about streaming instead of loading:

> Instead of using a job to load data into BigQuery, you can choose to
>   stream your data into BigQuery one record at a time by using the
>   tabledata().insertAll() method.

Last thing about [streaming inserts (insertAll)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery):

> Ensure that you have write access to the dataset that
>   contains your destination table. **The table must exist before you begin
>   writing data to it unless you are using template tables**. For more
>   information on template tables, see Creating tables automatically
>   using template tables.

If you still want to load instead of stream with template table and create table in the same time please use Jobs and [load type of job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load) (or other type if needed)

Example code from my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42921788/how-to-create-table-without-schema-in-bigquery-by-api):

```
Insert insert = bigquery.jobs().insert(projectId,
                   new Job().setConfiguration(
                            new JobConfiguration().setLoad(
                                   new JobConfigurationLoad()
                                                .setSourceFormat("NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON")
                                                .setDestinationTable(
                                                        new TableReference()
                                                                .setProjectId(projectId)
                                                                .setDatasetId(dataSetId)
                                                                .setTableId(tableId)
                                                )
                                                .setCreateDisposition("CREATE_IF_NEEDED")
                                                .setWriteDisposition(writeDisposition)
                                                .setSourceUris(Collections.singletonList(sourceUri))
                                                .setAutodetect(true)
                                )
                        ));

Job myInsertJob = insert.execute();
```